# Kotlin Android - ImageView in ListView

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I'm using an ArrayAdapter to populate my listView:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(applicationContext, R.layout.listview_text, emailAddresses)
listView.adapter = adapter
```

and this layout for custom textView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:background="#FFFFFF"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:paddingTop="35dp"
          android:fontFamily="@font/familiar_pro_bold"
          android:textColor="#212121"
          android:id="@+id/listText"/>
```

Now, I want to display an icon (as a "view full item") at right of each items (which are added by user).

I want to avoid hundred of lines of code just for an image, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:paddingTop="35dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/familiar_pro_bold"
      android:textColor="#212121"
      android:id="@+id/listText"
      android:drawableRight="@drawable/view_full_item"/>
```

Also you can add some padding with `android:drawablePadding=xdp`